# using variables to name a column in MySQLi table

Tags: mysqli

I am trying to create a table on the MySQLi server using input from user. This means some of the columns' names will be determined by the user input. These input can even be "" if the user does not want it. Hence nu of table columns will vary. I am finding it difficult to achieve this. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
$prj = test_input($_POST["project"]);
$recipe1 = test_input($_POST["recipe1"]);
$recipe2 = test_input($_POST["recipe2"]);
$recipe3 = test_input($_POST["recipe3"]);
$recipe4 = test_input($_POST["recipe4"]);
$tblname = test_input($_POST["prjtitle"]);

$tableExists = mysqli_query($conn, "DESCRIBE $tblname");
if (TRUE) {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tblname (
    id INT(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    $name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    $prj VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    $recipe1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    $recipe2 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    $recipe3 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    $recipe4 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    reg_date TIMESTAMP
    )";

   if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
       echo "Table " .$tblname. " created successfully";
       } else {
           echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Note that $recipe2, $recipe3, $recipe4 can have a value "" This means the user does not need the column & as such the column should not be create.
How can I correct above syntax?

Comment: Build $sql in stages with If-Then-Else logic so that $recipe2, $recipe3, and $recipe4 are not there if they are blank.

Comment: @WillG txs for your input. I tried the following syntax which didn't work.     if ($recipe2 !== "")
$recipe2 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

Answer (score 0):

You should check it one by one.

```
$userColumn = ($recipe1 == "" ? "" : $recipe1." VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,");
$userColumn += ($recipe2 == "" ? "" : $recipe2." VARCHAR(10) NULL,");
$userColumn += ($recipe3 == "" ? "" : $recipe3." VARCHAR(10) NULL,");
$userColumn += ($recipe4 == "" ? "" : $recipe4." VARCHAR(10) NULL,");
```

then change if statement from

```
if (TRUE) {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tblname (
    id INT(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    $name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    $prj VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    $recipe1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    $recipe2 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    $recipe3 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    $recipe4 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    reg_date TIMESTAMP
    )";
```

to

```
if (TRUE) {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tblname (
    id INT(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    $name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    $prj VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    $userColumn
    reg_date TIMESTAMP
    )";
```

Finally the code is below

```
<?php
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
$prj = test_input($_POST["project"]);
$recipe1 = test_input($_POST["recipe1"]);
$recipe2 = test_input($_POST["recipe2"]);
$recipe3 = test_input($_POST["recipe3"]);
$recipe4 = test_input($_POST["recipe4"]);
$tblname = test_input($_POST["prjtitle"]);

$userColumn = ($recipe1 == "" ? "" : $recipe1." VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,");
$userColumn += ($recipe2 == "" ? "" : $recipe2." VARCHAR(10) NULL,");
$userColumn += ($recipe3 == "" ? "" : $recipe3." VARCHAR(10) NULL,");
$userColumn += ($recipe4 == "" ? "" : $recipe4." VARCHAR(10) NULL,");

$tableExists = mysqli_query($conn, "DESCRIBE $tblname");
if (TRUE) {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tblname (
    id INT(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    $name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    $prj VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    $userColumn
    reg_date TIMESTAMP
    )";

   if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
       echo "Table " .$tblname. " created successfully";
       } else {
           echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

See 'Conditional Operator' section in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_operator_types.htm for more information about ?: operator.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it isn't working. I keep getting the error message:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\wamp\www\tbl.php on line ....

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to insert ')' at the end of line, please try again.

Comment: Not working still. I got the error:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0', Project VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, .....    I guess this is a reference to the line: $userColumn

Comment: Please echo $sql and copy it, I would like to check.

Comment: @ Adisak Anusornsrirung You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0' Recipe1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, ......    Note that Recipe1 is not a variable. Txs

Answer (score 0):

The code below works just fine. :

```
   <?php
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
$prj = test_input($_POST["project"]);
$recipe1 = test_input($_POST["recipe1"]);
$recipe2 = test_input($_POST["recipe2"]);
$recipe3 = test_input($_POST["recipe3"]);
$recipe4 = test_input($_POST["recipe4"]);
$tblname = test_input($_POST["prjtitle"]);

$recipe2 = (empty($_POST["recipe2"])) ? "recipe2" :     
test_input($_POST["recipe2"]);
$recipe3 = (empty($_POST["recipe3"])) ? "recipe3" : 
test_input($_POST["recipe3"]);
$recipe4 = (empty($_POST["recipe4"])) ? "recipe4" : 
test_input($_POST["recipe4"]);

$tableExists = mysqli_query($conn, "DESCRIBE $tblname");
if (TRUE) {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tblname (
    id INT(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    $name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    $prj VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,

    $recipe1 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    $recipe2 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    $recipe3 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    $recipe4 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,  

    reg_date TIMESTAMP
    )";

   if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
       echo "Table " .$tblname. " created successfully";
       } else {
           echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```